# Python: Creating a function that extracts a range of rows from a dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a function that extracts a range of rows (n:m) from a dataset (.csv). It should ignore the first row, also, it should convert in integer the "Number Minutes" column.

Our dataset ("file_name.csv") would look like this:

```
﻿Name;Age;Team;Number Minutes
Henry Dalton;19;Chelsea FC;1.200
John Smith;50;Manchester Utd.;4.000
Herman Lock;32;Manchester City;2.400
Kyle Hard;23;Everton Football Club;1.200
```

The function would look like this:

```
 find_player("file_name.csv", 2, 3)
```

And the outcome would be:

```
['John Smith' , '50' , 'Manchester Utd.' '4000']
['Herman Lock' , '32' , 'Manchester City' , '2400']
```

I've chose to use pandas. So far I've made this code:

```
import pandas as pd
file_route = r'.\file_name.csv'

def find_player(file_route, n, m):
    data = pd.read.csv(file_route)
    data2 = data[n, m].copy()
    data2[3] = data2[3].astype(int)
    print(data2)
    return(data2)
```

I can't get the correct solution, so I could use some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def find_player(filename,start,end):
    with open(filename, 'r') as msg:
        data = msg.read().splitlines() 
    return [[int(s.replace(".","")) if s.replace(".","").isdigit() else s for s in item.split(";")] for item in data[start:end+1]]

print (find_player("file_name.csv", 2, 3))
```

Output:

```
[['John Smith', 50, 'Manchester Utd.', 4000], ['Herman Lock', 32, 'Manchester City', 2400]]
```

Please note than you can't really get two lists as shown in your example. Either you get a list of lists, either you run your function once per line you want to catch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And how could I convert my last column into integer as shown in the example?

Comment: You are not really converting to int, you are multiplying it by 1000 and converting to int

Comment: @Hugo, that's what the OP wants I think. At least that is what I understand from it. Remove the period, set to int. I imagine 3.00000 should give 300000. So I do not multiply, I replace and set to int

Answer (score 1):

To select a range of rows you can simple do the same thing you would do with a list

```
n = 1
m = 2
data = pd.read_csv('./file_name.csv',delimiter=';',dtype={'Number Minutes': 'float'})
selection = data[n:m]
```

The *dtype* parameter allows you to set the type for a specific column

Answer (score 1):

In case you still want to use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd


def find_player(file_route, n, m):
    original_data = pd.read_csv(file_route, sep=';')
    selected_data = original_data[n - 1:m]
    selected_data['Number Minutes'] = (selected_data['Number Minutes'] * 1000).astype(int)
    final_list = selected_data.values.tolist()
    return final_list


file = r'.\file1.csv'

print(find_player(file, 2, 3))
```